# Using a For loop in Python to add up all un-even increments between 3-27?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to use `range()` to write a `for` loop that starts at three and adds up all non-even increments of 3 less than 30. It's supposed to print 75. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(3,30,3):
    sumw=0
    if (i%2) != 0:
        sumw += i
        print(sumw)
```

^^This is what I have, but it only returns the numbers that are supposed to be added.

Also if you could show me how to do the same thing using a `while` loop, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is relatively simple once you realise that the indentation of the final line is such that it prints the running sum after every loop, and that the accumulator is reset *inside* the loop. What you need to do is stop resetting and then print it once the loop is *finished:*

```
sumw = 0
for i in range(3,30,3):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        sumw += i
print(sumw)
```

As to using a `while` loop, the following two are equivalent but I would still maintain that the first is better:

```
for i in range(3,30,3):
    doSomethingWith(i)

i = 3
while i < 30:
    doSomethingWith(i)
    i += 3
```

A reasonable *general* rule is to use the former when you know everything about the loop itself beforehand, that latter when things *within* the loop may affect how the loop terminates.

And, of course, a more pythonic way to get the sum would be by understanding that odd numbers starting at three can be achieved by adding six rather than three, and using the stuff already built in to Python (the `sum` function in this case):

```
sumw = sum(range(3, 30, 6)) # 3, 9, 15, 21, 27.
```

Using the more expressive parts of Python are a good way to *avoid* problems such as the one in your original code.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Your problem is you keep resetting `sumw` to `0` within the `for` loop. Try this:

```
sumw = 0
for i in range(3, 30, 3):
  if (i%2) != 0:
    sumw += i
print(sumw)
```

This should print

```
75
```

Using a `while` loop is also trivial:

```
i = 3
sum = 0
while i < 30:
  if (i%2) != 0:
    sumw += i
  i += 3
```

As a side note, you can omit the `!= 0` check and simply write

```
if i % 2:
```

Because any non-zero numeric value is logically equivalent to `True`.

Finally, for future reference, you could have solved the problem in a single line using a generator expression:

```
>>> print(sum(i for i in range(3, 30, 3) if i % 2))
75
```

Comment: Wow so simple, thanks a ton! also as for the last part, it had to be in a while and a for loop due to directions. thank you!!